# How do I get rid of the empty space in my ggplot2 bloxplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I am using this code in RStudio to make a boxplot, but I am left with a large blank area to the right of my data.  Any idea how to get rid of it? Otherwise it looks how I want it to.

```
bvt <- Awake_Protists_Combined_Results %>%
  ggplot(aes(Treatment, `log cfu/Root Fraction`)) +
  geom_boxplot() + 
  scale_x_discrete(limits= Awake_Protists_Combined_Results$Treatment) +
  geom_jitter(height = 0, width = 0.5, alpha = 0.2) + 
  ylim(0,10) + 
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle = 65, hjust = 1))
```

Large blank area to the right of my data. how do I get rid of it?

[image]

Comment: What happens if you remove `scale_x_discrete()`?

Comment: When I remove scale_x_discrete, the excess blank space goes away, but then my x axis reverts to alphabetical order, which I don't want.  Is there another way to put my x axis in this specific order?

Comment: Change to `scale_x_discrete(limits= unique(Awake_Protists_Combined_Results$Treatment))`

Comment: That worked - thank you!!

Comment: The reason why you were getting this behaviour is because you were passing in the entire column of data from your data frame as the x-axis when you just wanted the unique instances of it.

Comment: Thank you for explaining why! I really appreciate your help.